# поиск и хранение в дереве (Tree) java

Tags: java, алгоритм, дерево

Всем ку! подскажите пож-та, есть определенного рода задача, предлагать пользаку  из словаря слово подобное тому что он вводит. Т.е. при каждом нажатии проверять есть ли такое подобное уже в словаре. Вопрос как хранить слова? в виде дерева и искать в нем? Если к примеру вводит "wo" и в словаре есть world и work то не предлагать ничего, подсказываем только тогда когда есть 1 вариант в словаре начинающийся с введенных символов. Соответственно вводимые новые слова, для которых не было вариантов, т.е. новое слово, надо добавлять в коллекцию (словарь).
Реализация на java

Comment: Можно построить `HashMap`, в которой ключом будет минимальный префикс слова, по которому оно однозначно идентифицируется, а значением - само слово. Тогда для ввода пользователя `wor` надо будет проверить `wor`, `wo` и `w`, пока не будет найдено соответствие. Если не жалко память, то можно все префиксы хранить.

Comment: https://github.com/arunkumar9t2/trie

Comment: уточню, например ключ wo, значением должно быть и world и work, как хранить? поиск по ключу же как я понял?

Comment: @Alexandr нет, ключа `wo` быть не должно, потому что для него значение не единственное. Аналогично для `wor`. А вот ключ `worl` будет. Это вы на стадии формирования `HashMap` должны отлавливать. Да, поиск по ключу. Ключи - варианты введённого пользователем текста (по очереди `wor`, `wo`, `w`).